# Having trouble getting some text. Python. Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to get the Finance data from this `div`. There is no unique identifier for this `div`. So, I collect all 3-4 `divs` check if the word `FINANSE` appears in the text, if it does, then get the inner `div` text. However, it doesn't seem to work. Any other approach or what am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

link = https://rejestr.io/krs/882875/fortuna-cargo

```
fin_divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.card.mb-4')
for div in fin_divs:
    if 'FINANSE' in div.text:
        finances = div.find_element_by_css_selector('div.card-body').text
    else:
        finances = "Finance Data Not Available"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code to select exact element instead of looping through list of elements:

```
finances = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[div="Finanse"]/div[@class="card-body"]').text
print(finances)

>>>Kapitał zakładowy
>>>5 tys. zł
```

Comment: Wow!..What is that? Can search for `div` text in the 'xpath` itself?

Comment: @AbhishekRai you can select element with exact text or element that *contains some partial text* (`div[contains(., "<PARTIAL_TEXT>")]`)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything correct, just add `break` into the `if` statement to not overwrite `finances` to `"Finance Data Not Available"` after finding correct one:

```
fin_divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.card.mb-4')
for div in fin_divs:
    if 'FINANSE' in div.text:
        finances = div.find_element_by_css_selector('div.card-body').text
        break
    else:
        finances = "Finance Data Not Available"
```